# Shared SimpleChannelHandler netty

Tags: java, performance, netty, shared

first of all, thank you to get on this question.

I've been finding for long time an answer to my question but badly there isn't any :/

What do you think it has better perfomance for a NIO environment (NETTY):

Instantiating the HandlerClass each time a connection arrives, or using a shared HandlerClass ? I.E:

---

```
...getPipeline() {
    pipeline = ...;
   pipeline.addLast("handler", new HandlerClass());
}
```

---

### OR:

```
private handlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
...getPipeline() {
    pipeline = ...;
   pipeline.addLast("handler", this.handler);
}
```

My gaming server will receive more than 1000 connections and that's a thing that i'm worrying about.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy...  If your SimpleChannelHandler has no state stored in vars reuse it. His way you remove the init cost of the new class and also hace less GC pressure.

Comment: But since the messageReceived(..) / writeRequested(..) methods will be accessed from lots of channels (connections) at the same time, wouldn't be saturated and in consequence slow to access & process data?

Thank you!

Comment: I've read the following statement some time ago and it's what i'm worrying about:

"in a multi-threaded application, remember that there is only one 'instance' of a Shared/static class, and that each thread with access to it will call the same thing, leading to possible thread locks and data corruption."

I'm worrying about threads waiting to access the Shared Class functions.

Comment: If you not have any "synchronized" etc in your handler it will not slow down things at all. As there will be no need to "fight" for a lock

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking to create a pooling system for your handler.  Assuming one handler can only handle one request at a time and you're app is highly concurrent.  This way you can keep handler object instantiated in memory for better performance.

I've had some luck using pool4j.  If that doesn't work for you, you will probably be best off writing your own pool.

http://code.google.com/p/pool4j/

Also poolit is a more generic library that I haven't personally used but I've heard good things about:
http://programming.huyduong.com/poolit/index.html

Comment: Netty auto-pools it by adding an executor to the pipeline

private handlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
...getPipeline() {
    pipeline = ...;
   pipeline.addLast("executor", new ExecutionHandler(new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(...))); // EXECUTOR MUST BE SHARED
}